# Problem with background location settings using NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsuserdefaults

I am storing Location settings in the settings bundle. So when I flip a switch to NO, my app stops the background location service.

I am using an observer to detect settings change, and updating a flag in my app. The problem is, if  I flip the switch to OFF, my app does not stop the location service till I open the app. This is understandable, since my observer resides in the source code. Is there a way to listen for the settings while the app is in the background? I am an iOS development newbie, so I do not understand the concept of background and foreground so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible is what I found.